# Any way to autopopulate HTML form textbox with data in URL string?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, url

Is it possible to autopopulate a textbox on a page depending on a string passed in with the URL.  For example:

Say we have the following form:

```
<form name="form_reservation" id="form-reservation">
                    <div style="padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;">
                    <label for="reservation-id">Reservation ID</label>
                        <input name="reservation_id" id="reservation-id" class="reservationid" style="width:120px !important"/>
                        <div style="padding:5px 20px 0px 10px;" class="res_message" id="res-message">&nbsp;</div>
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search Reservation" name="search_button" style="width:150px !important; margin:10px 0px 0px 5px;"/>
                        <input type="button" class="button" value="Clear" style="width:150px !important; margin:10px 0px 0px 5px;" onclick="resetForms('reservation')" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And the user received an email with a link in it:  www.website.com/formpage.html######

Where ###### was the ID that I wanted to populate in the reservation-id field on the form.  Any way to make this happen?

Comment: Do you mean a URL like this: `formpage.html#1234` or like `formpage.html?id=1234`?

Comment: And do you want to do it in PHP or in Javascript? Your question has both tags.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am open to both.  I suppose I would see javascript as maybe being easier from my perspective, but am not opposed to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the URL the user clicks looks like `www.website.com/formpage.html?id=12345`, you can spit it out into the input "value" field with GET, e.g.:

```
<input value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]); ?>" name="reservation_id" id="reservation-id" class="reservationid" style="width:120px !important" />
```

This is the way to do it with php.

EDIT:

Per @Esailija's comment, I wrapped it in the htmlspecialchars function, which as far as I understand will help safeguard against XSS attacks.

Comment: Add `addslashes($_GET["id"])` so there will be no surprises.

Comment: @Dobiatowski what is the point of addslashes? This is vulnerable to XSS which cannot be avoided with addslashes. Html is escaped with `&quot;` etc. Also, -1.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', ''); // get hash and replace the '#' (hash) tag
    document.getElementById('reservation-id').value = hash; // add value to input
</script>
```

I assumed you were talking about hash location `url.html#1111`, this can be accomplished only in JavaScript.

Comment: I do like the idea of accomplishing this with JS... should this function be placed in the Header of the HTML?

Comment: if you wish to put that in the header you must execute it after the page load, otherwise put it after your form